# Usar metodos del componente padre, desde el componente hijo Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo un componente Modal-dialog donde el boton confirmar deberia (aparte de otra funcion) ejecutar un metodo que pertenece al componente padre "app.componet.ts"

dDeseo que el hijo, en este caso dicho dialog ejecute una funcion que pertenece al padre, no se como. Alguna guia?

Answer (score 1):

Para eso, lo que tendrás que hacer es definir en la clase hijo un atributo @Output, que será el evento que se lance hacia el componente padre, y el padre tendrá que capturar ese evento y ejecutar su función:

```js
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() fatherNameFunction = new EventEmitter<void>();

  childFunction() {
    // Aquí haces lo que el componente hijo tenga que hacer y lanzas el evento al padre
    this.fatherNameFunction.emit();
  }
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-father-component',
  template: `
    <app-child-component
      (fatherNameFunction)="onEventLaunched($event)">
    </app-child-component>
  `
})
export class FatherComponent {

  onEventLaunched() {
    // Aquí iría lo que el padre tenga que hacer
  }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, perfecto